# "Propendere": dual forms for the participio passato?

Tags: verbs, past-participle

Some verbs have dual forms for the participio passato, for example retrocedere (retrocesso, retroceduto). In this case WordReference (https://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx?v=retrocedere) lists both forms. But for the verb propendere (https://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx?v=propendere) it gives only a single form: propeso. Whereas Educalingo (https://educalingo.com/it/dic-it/propendere) gives only the single form propenduto.
If the two forms are both commonly used, why does WR give only one? If one is much more common than the other, which is it?

Comment: If I understand the contents of the ["propendere" voice of Treccani dictionary](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/propendere), "propenduto" is not used and "propeso" is rare.

Comment: As to the question “why does WR give [so and so]”, the answer is that WordReference is not an actual, reliable reference work, with an actual, reliable editing team and publisher; it's an amateurish “repository” (as it defines itself) of lots of heterogeneous stuff, often with no author or source given.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!  I might add that the Devoto-Oli online dictionary gives just "propeso" as the participio passato.  Devoto-Oli appears to be a "reliable reference work".  But. as best I can tell, so is Educalingo, with its "propenduto".  Thus my confusion.  Perhaps I should downgrade Educalingo. I use WR despite knowing it is "amatuerish".  One needs to double-check with other sources if something seems fishy. Which led to my confusion.  WR does note that the compound tenses for propendere are rare.  So propeso is "rare" only in the sense that it is rarely needed.

Comment: Educalingo is a repository of diverse stuff too. If I don't see something attributed to work X, linguist Y, publishing house Z, it might well be made up, illegally copied or whatever. Linguists, lexicographers etc. are of course fallible, but about an unknown authority I cannot even have a general opinion. My best bet for learning about a language are (real) monolingual dictionaries. Yes, Devoto-Oli is one of the good ones, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The book *Italiano* by Serianni says (XI.280) that the normal form is *propenso* (not **propeso*), while *propenduto* exists but is uncommon. This certainly confirms my experience as a native speaker (I do not think I ever heard or read the form *propenduto*).

As an aside, while *retroceduto* does not feel "wrong" (probably by the influence of the by now fully regularized *cedere*), I would still consider much more common the form *retrocesso*.

Comment: The Treccani dictionary propends for *propeso* as a rare form past participle, while it says that *propenduto* is not used.

Comment: To add a data point, the paywalled Zingarelli dictionary also gives only the form _propeso_, marking it as rare. On the other hand, both Treccani and Zingarelli give as the etymology of _propenso_ the past participle of the Latin verb _propendere_. Finally, Migliorini, Tagliavini and Fiorelli's _Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronunzia_ give _propenduto_ as the (rare) past participle. I'll try and check more dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks! See comments above.  I'll take a look at Zingarelli.

Comment: It is true that the past participle of *propendere* exists mainly as an adjective (in the form *propenso*). I don't think I've ever seen either *propeso* or *propenduto*...